# Custom Endpoints Woocommerce with WP Jobmanager

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

we´ve inserted some new ednpoints to the my account section of woocommerce. For some reason, a few of them have no navigation.

The Endpoints are working, but as I mentioned above, some of them have no no navigation.
Can anyone help`?

Tried to set the endpoints up again. But when I got the endpoints they have no action, like you are not able to "relist" a listing and so on

```
enter code here
<? /* SET NEW ENDPOINT FOR MEINE KLEINANZEIGEN IN MY ACCOUNT*/


    function mein_stellenangebot_endpoint() {

    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'mein_stellenangebot', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );

}

add_action( 'init', 'mein_stellenangebot' );
```

// ------------------

```
// 2. Add new query var

function mein_stellenangebot_query_vars( $vars ) {

    $vars[] = 'mein_stellenangebot';

    return $vars;

}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'mein_stellenangebot_query_vars', 0 );
```

// ------------------

// 3. Insert the new endpoint into the My Account menu

```
function mein_stellenangebot_link_my_account( $items ) {

    $items['mein_stellenangebot'] = 'Stellenangebot';

    return $items;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 
'mein_stellenangebot_link_my_account' );
```

// ------------------

// 4. Add content to the new endpoint

```
function mein_stellenangebot_content() {


echo do_shortcode( ' [job_dashboard] ' );

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_mein_stellenangebot_endpoint', 
'mein_stellenangebot_content' );
```

and re-sort the them via this:

```
<? function wpb_woo_my_account_order() {
$myorder = array(
‘dashboard’ => __( ‘Dashboard’, ‘woocommerce’ ),
‘orders’ => __( ‘Bestellungen’, ‘woocommerce’ ),
‘mein_stellenangebot’ => __( ‘Meine Stellenangebote’, ‘woocommerce’ ),
‘meine_stellengesuche’ => __( ‘Meine Stellengesuche’, ‘woocommerce’ ),
‘meine_bewerbung’ => __( ‘Bewerbungen’, ‘woocommerce’ ),
‘favoriten’ => __( ‘Favoriten’, ‘woocommerce’ ),
‘stellenalarm’ => __( ‘Stellenalarm’, ‘woocommerce’ ),
‘statistik’ => __( ‘Statistik’, ‘woocommerce’ ),
‘meine_praxisanzeigen’ => __( ‘Meine Praxisanzeigen’, ‘woocommerce’ ),
‘meine_kleinanzeigen’ => __( ‘Meine Kleinanzeigen’, ‘woocommerce’ ),
‘edit-account’ => __( ‘Kontodetails’, ‘woocommerce’ ),
‘customer-logout’ => __( ‘Abmelden’, ‘woocommerce’ ),
);
return $myorder;
}
add_filter ( ‘woocommerce_account_menu_items’, ‘wpb_woo_my_account_order’ 
);`
```